# Prove that if both $a$ and $a^m$ have order $n$, then $\gcd(m,n) = 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group, and $a \in G$ has order $n$. Suppose also that there is an integer $m > 1$ such that $a^m$ has order $n$.

> Prove: $\gcd(m,n) = 1$

What I have so far:

$\text{order}(a^m) = n$, so we have

$$(a^m)^n = a^{mn} = e = a^n$$

where $e$ is the identity. How do we go from here to $\gcd(m,n) = 1$?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint:  you need to use the part of the definition of "order" that says that $n$ is the *smallest* power that gives the identity element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot derive it from that information. What you can show in this way is that the order of $a^m$ will always be at most $n$, and thus divide $n$.

To show what you want you can proceed like this.

Let $d = \gcd(m,n)$. Then $(a^{m})^{n/d} = (a^{n})^{m/d}= e^{m/d} =e$. 
Note that this is valid because $d\mid m$ and $d \mid n$ so $m/d$ and $n/d$ are integers.

Thus the order of $a^m$ is at most $n/d$. Thus if it is $n$, then $n \le n/d$ and thus $d=1$.